# Launch a webview with POST parameters

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I would like to navigate to a webview with a distant URI, which needs POST parameters to display correct data.

Did anyone realize this in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps ?

For the moment, I succeeded to retrieve a httpResponse :

```
string url = "https://v3.goomeoevents.fr/webview/networking/msge";
uri UriToNavigate = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
var client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = null;
HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = null;
HttpMethod methodPOST = HttpMethod.Post;
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(methodPOST, UriToNavigate);

postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("lang","fr-FR");
requestMessage.Content = new HugeFormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

httpResponse = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

Comment: Using `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` is the best option so far, then just navigate the `WebView` to the retrieved page.

Comment: Indeed this is way better. Thank you kiewic